# What does "death's head apparition"mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> To have painted the sordid facts of their lives, and they throughout
> invoking the death’s head apparition of the family gentility to come
> and scare their benefactors, would have made Young John a satirist of
> the first water.

The preceding text is from Charles Dickens' *Little Dorrit* chapter 20. What does **death's head apparition** mean, and why would it scare their benefactors?

Comment: Please indicate what research you've done. Do you know the literal meaning of death's head?

Comment: The Dorrit family's insistence that they are 'genteel' despite their impoverished circumstances is likened to a scarey ghost.

Answer (score 2):

[*Death's head*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death%27s-head) is an image of the human skull. It's [widely used in art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_skull_symbolism) to illustrate different ideas.

The exact meaning here would depend on the context and how the Dorrit family presents (or hides) its history (which is not clear without reading more of the book).

[The cited text](https://www.shmoop.com/little-dorrit/book-1-chapter-20-full-text.html) goes on to make a couple more references to the "*family skeleton*":

> When this spirited young man and his sister had begun systematically to produce the family skeleton for the overawing of the College, this narrative cannot precisely state. Probably at about the period when they began to dine on the College charity. It is certain that the more reduced and necessitous they were, the more pompously the skeleton emerged from its tomb; and that when there was anything particularly shabby in the wind, the skeleton always came out with the ghastliest flourish.

It seems there is something terrible, scary or pitiful about the family fate which is either used to scare people or which is being concealed for fear of scaring people.